# When superset connect to kylin,table not found error occured

Tags: apache-superset, kylin

I followed the steps from the http://kylin.apache.org/blog/2018/01/01/kylin-and-superset/ to connect Apache Superset with Kylin.

When I click the "Test Connection" button, I get the popup that says:

> "Seems OK!"

But when I am trying to add a table in the next step, I get the following error message:

> "Table [KYLIN_ACCOUNT] could not be found, please double check your
>   database connection, schema, and table name"

Know someone who can answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please double check that your SCHEMA is correct.